# How do I take code from a raspberry pi and store it onto a smaller chip so I don't have to use the pi over and over again

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2

I bought a raspberry pi and created a small remote controlled truck, but I want to work on more projects; is there any way to sore the Python file onto a flashdrive and connect it to some kind of cpu so the truck will still work and I can use the pi for other things and continue buying the small "cpu" uploading the pythons code and moving forward on different projects?

Comment: Are you looking for a [microcontroller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller)?

Answer (score 0):

You've written in a high-level language for specific hardware.

You could make your own ARM Cortex-A7 based board but it'll be cheaper to just buy another Pi.

If you want to make small inexpensive devices, then you should use a lower-level language with a microcontroller, such as Atmel AVR, found in Arduinos.